# Migrate database values in Django

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a db table 'UserSite' with User, Site and Group in it. A site is from a user and can put into just one group. Now I want a user to be able to add a site to multiple groups. Therefor I created a new db table UserSiteGroups to handle the many to many relation. So I need to migrate all the group keys from the old UserSite table to the new UserSiteGroups table.

I want to do is by a migrations script. I already made a migration to create a new database table UserSiteGroups with user, site and group. Now I just need to copy the values. I have this migration script:

```
from django.db import migrations


def migrate_groups_data(apps, schema_editor):
    UserSiteGroup = apps.get_model("site", "UserSiteGroup")
    UserSite = apps.get_model("site", "UserSite")
    # UserSiteGroup.objects.all().update(group=F("groups"))

    for user_site in UserSite.objects.all():
        usersitegroup = UserSiteGroup.Objects.filter(
            user_site__user=user_site.user, user_site__site=user_site.site
        ).first()
        usersitegroup.group = user_site.group
        usersitegroup.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [("site", "0035_usersitegroup")]
    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(migrate_groups_data),
    ]
```

but I got this error-log:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column site_usersite.group_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...s_is_muted", "site_usersite"."notes_is_muted", "site_u...
...
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column site_usersite.group_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...s_is_muted", "site_usersite"."notes_is_muted", "site_u...
```

usersitegroup migration:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.9 on 2020-01-22 14:46

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("groups", "0001_initial"),
        ("st_site", "0034_auto_20200122_1422"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="UserSiteGroup",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.AutoField(
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        verbose_name="ID",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "group",
                    models.ForeignKey(
                        on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                        related_name="usersites",
                        to="groups.Group",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "usersite",
                    models.ForeignKey(
                        on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,
                        related_name="groups",
                        to="st_site.UserSite",
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Did you first make a migration that altered the structure of your table? It looks like you do a data migration *before* these columns actually exist.

Comment: Yes I did. I did a migration to make UserSiteGroup with id, group and usersite

Comment: so that is done in the `0035_usersitegroup`?

Comment: yes, indeed. I shall post that one in the question

Comment: don't look to the difference between st_site and site.